# getting undeclared identifier in code copied from a book

Tags: c++

Well I think the below program is okay but it is giving following error

> op: undeclared identifier

I just cant understand why this is happening because it is the same exact code I copied it from "programming principles and practice using c++".

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    cout << "Please enter an expression. We can handle +,-,* and /" << "\n";
    cout << "Add an x to end expression" << "\n";

    int lval = 0;
    int rval;

    cin >> lval;
    if (!cin) error("No first operand");
    for (char op; cin >> op;)
        if (op != 'x') cin >> rval;
    if (!cin) error("No second operand");

    switch (op) {

    case'+':
        lval += rval;
        break;

    case'-':
        lval -= rval;
        break;

    case'*':
        lval *= rval;
        break;

    case'/':
        lval /= rval;
        break;

    default:

        cout << "Result: " << lval << '\n';
        keep_window_open();
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: When posting questions about errors, please include (in the question body) the *complete* and *unedited* error output, also indicate where in the in the included source the error(s) are, e.g. by a comment, I suggest you  please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: amazing how many books with poor C++ programs are around *and* still read.

Comment: What edition is your book and what page/chapter is the code in?

Answer (score 6):

The scope of variables declared in for loops is limited to the for loop.  In order to use `op` outside the for loop you need to change it to

```
char op;
for (; cin >> op;)
```

But while we are changing things lets just make this a while loop

```
char op;
while (cin >> op)
```

Some compilers allowed using variables declared in a for loop outside the for loop but that is not standard and it should not be relied on.  An easy way to tell if you have a non conforming compiler is to run

```
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 0; i++) {}
    i++;
}
```

The `i++` should cause an error([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbaf94b3d793f7fb)).